# Error in replacing pattern with `sed` command

Tags: sed, replace, text-processing

I am trying to replace occurrences of pattern in a file. Lines in the file look like this:

```
****time is = 0000
****time is = 0001
```

I am trying to search string by case insensitive `time is` and want to replace `time is = xxxx` by `****`.

I tried using `sed 's/time \ is/.*' filename.txt`

But I get error `sed: -e expression #1, char : unterminated 's' command`

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I corrected the command.  `sed 's/time \ is/.*/' filename.txt` But this places `.* = xxxx` This is not I wanted. I wanted to replace the entire pattern by `****`.

`Original line: ****time is = 0000`

`Desired output: ********`

Any sugegstions?

Comment: If you really typed it that way, you are missing the closing quote after the asterisk.

Comment: Sorry that was typo in question. Corrected.

Comment: you are missing ending '/' as well.

Comment: Please show the desired output for your sample input. Your current description can be read as if you want "********" for both input lines as resulting output.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `sed 's/time is.*/****/' filename.txt`.. regarding case insensitive, if see if your sed supports `i` or `I` flag.. `'s/time is.*/****/I'`... else, you can use `'s/[tT][iI][mM][eE] [iI][sS].*/****/'`

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Can you explain what `.*` in `time is.*` does?

Comment: @er34456 `.*` is a regular expression that matches everything.